# Map.find and Map.tryFind returning unexpected results

Tags: f#

This is probably something obvious but banging my head against a wall here...

I have a value:

```
dailyCandleMap : Map<DayOfWeek, List<TimeSpan * TimeSpan> option>
```

I ensured that keys for each day of the week are present so I should safely be able to use Map.find to retrieve the `List<TimeSpan * TimeSpan> option` for a given day. I've tried the following:

```
let candlesForMonday = Map.find(DayOfWeek.Monday, dailyCandleMap)
```

But hovering over the type for `candlesForMonday` the compiler tells me that it is

```
(Map<(DayOfWeek * Map<DayOfWeek, List<TimeSpan * TimeSpan> option>), obj> -> obj)
```

What the heck does this mean and how is it possible given the signature for Map.find which is `'Key -> Map<'Key,'T> -> 'T`?

EDIT: As I'm playing around with this more I see that its a problem with curried form/partial application and the way I was calling the function. Doing it this way gives me the expected result:

```
let candlesForMonday = Map.find DayOfWeek.Monday dailyCandleMap
```

Would still really appreciate someone to help clarify what is really going with the previous wrong example though because the resulting type signature hurts my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the type of `find` is `'Key -> Map<'Key, 'T> -> 'T`. So `find` is a curried function taking two argument (i.e. it is a function taking one argument and then returning another function that takes another argument). The type of the first function is `'Key`, which is a type variable.

When you do `Map.find(DayOfWekk.Monday, dailyCandleMap)`, you're calling `find` with one argument: a tuple containing `Monday` and `dailyCandleMap`. So in that call the type variable `'Key` takes the type `DayOfWeek * Map<DayOfWeek, List<TimeSpan * TimeSpan> option>`. Therefore the function returned by `find` has type `Map<(DayOfWeek * Map<DayOfWeek, List<TimeSpan * TimeSpan> option>), 'T> -> 'T`. That is it takes a map whose keys are `DayOfWeek`-`Map`-tuples and returns the value, for which the given tuple was the key. Since there is no additional information about what `'T` is, the type inference decides that `'T` is `obj`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My F# has gotten a lot better but I'm still weak at reading those signatures properly sometimes. Gotta remember what the -> means when looking at these